# Session в php

Tags: сессия, php

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию с помощью сессии

В $_SESSION['user'] запихиваю объект юзера, авторизация вроде как и  прошла, но потом получается, что если открыть адрес с любого компа, то везде страница уже авторизирована, как такое может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а проверку на совпадение куки делал? По идее ты должен сохранять уникальный код сессии в базу допустим поле hash при авторизации, потом просто сверять hash сессии с hash в базе данных если они совпадают, то показывать данные закрытых страниц. Сессия живет только до выключения компьютера (если я не ошибаюсь) или ей можно установить время жизни.  При следующей авторизации ты просто обновляешь hash в базе на текущий.

Comment: Спасибо, в базе не хранил, но ошибка была в другом: по ошибке, я любому юзеру явно задавал одну и ту же session_id, но даже если хранить в базе уникальную и увести авторизационную куку, то подставить можно, люди советуют хранить хеш от сессии + ip

Comment: во во во! ip у пользователей, как правило, динамический.