# Сессии в php. Вопрос по поводу вопроса.

Tags: сессия, php

Увидел [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295319/session-%D0%B2-php)

Странно, но я тоже использую SESSION для авторизации. Просто при авторизации прописываю $_SESSION['user']='user' и ничего больше. Никаких записей в БД не делаю при этом. Однако после авторизации не могу не только войти на сайт с другого компа, но и со своего компа через другой браузер. Это я чего-то не понимаю, или ТС?

Comment: ну там же явно было, что ТС сглючил, запись в базу это в случае хранения сессий в базе.  а так, там же все элементарно. 

    охрана: - ваш пропуск!
    вы: нет :/
    охрана: ваш пасспорт!
    вы показываете 
    охрана смотрит по компу куда у вас есть допуск и выдает вам бумажку со штрих-кодом и говорит, что это пропуск

    в след раз:

    охрана: ваш пропуск!
    вы: вот!
    охрана считывает штрихкод и смотрит в базу, не протух ли ваш пропуск, совпадает ли ваша фотка с тем что они видят, и говорит: проходите

Comment: @eicto, понятно. Как легко меня ввести в заблуждение. Я уже было подумал, что все мои проекты неправильно построены. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

во первых это массив, ну это не главное. Суть в том, что туда обычно записывается какая-нибудь константа при удачной авторизации. Когда юзер отдаёт данные надо их сравнить с базой и если совпадают то пишем в $_SESSION что-нибудь. Тут вроде описано [Сессии PHP - теория](http://softodon.com/article-761-sessii-php-teoriya.html)

Comment: поспешил, ща исправлю вопрос